# Access hadoop nodes web UI from multiple links

Tags: hadoop

i am using the following setup for hadoop's nodes web ui access :

```
dfs.namenode.http-address : 127.0.0.1:50070
```

By which i am able to access the nodes web ui link only form the local machine as :

```
http://127.0.0.1:50070
```

Is there any way by which i can make it accessible from outside as well ? say like :

```
http://<Machine-IP>:50070
```

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Haven't tried it yourself?

Comment: @kumar please see my comment "make it accessible from outside as well " .. when i change the property dfs.namenode.http-address from 127... to localhost / machine ip, then i will be able to access the web ui like "http://<Machine-IP>:50070" .. and this (http://127.0.0.1:50070) wont work anymore. I need both the url to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hostname or ipaddress instead of localhost/127.0.0.1.

Make sure you can ping the hostname or ip from the remote machine. If you can ping it then you can able to access web ui.

To ping it

1. Open cmd/terminal
2. type the below command in remote machines

   ping hostname/ip

Comment: Thanks for the quick respsonse .. but i am looking for a way to access the web UI form both the following ways : http://127.0.0.1:50070 and http://<Machine-IP>:50070.

Comment: Just set the machine ip in the configuration files, then you can access by both way.

Comment: Use hostname, it will be meaningful and can access from any other remote machines.

Comment: I had the same doubt too. I can ping my ip from remote machine. But I am unable to access web UI.

Comment: Did you accesses your web ui with ipaddress? What error you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-web-interfaces.html

> The following table lists web interfaces that you can view on the core
>   and task nodes. These Hadoop interfaces are available on all clusters.
>   To access the following interfaces, replace `slave-public-dns-name` in
>   the URI with the public DNS name of the node. For more information
>   about retrieving the public DNS name of a core or task node instance,
>   see Connecting to Your Linux/Unix Instances Using SSH in the *Amazon
>   EC2 User Guide for Linux Instances*. In addition to retrieving the
>   public DNS name of the core or task node, you must also edit the
>   ElasticMapReduce-slave security group to allow SSH access over TCP
>   port 22. For more information about modifying security group rules,
>   see Adding Rules to a Security Group in the *Amazon EC2 User Guide for
>   Linux Instances*.
>
> - YARN ResourceManager
> - YARN NodeManager
> - Hadoop HDFS NameNode
> - Hadoop HDFS DataNode
> - Spark HistoryServer
>
> Because there are several application-specific interfaces available on
>   the master node that are not available on the core and task nodes, the
>   instructions in this document are specific to the Amazon EMR master
>   node. Accessing the web interfaces on the core and task nodes can be
>   done in the same manner as you would access the web interfaces on the
>   master node.
>
> There are several ways you can access the web interfaces on the master
>   node. The easiest and quickest method is to use SSH to connect to the
>   master node and use the text-based browser, Lynx, to view the web
>   sites in your SSH client. However, Lynx is a text-based browser with a
>   limited user interface that cannot display graphics. The following
>   example shows how to open the Hadoop ResourceManager interface using
>   Lynx (Lynx URLs are also provided when you log into the master node
>   using SSH).
>
> ```
> Copy lynx http://ip-###-##-##-###.us-west-2.compute.internal:8088/
> ```
>
> There are two remaining options for accessing web interfaces on the
>   master node that provide full browser functionality. Choose one of the
>   following:
>
> - Option 1 (recommended for more technical users): Use an SSH client to connect to the master node, configure SSH tunneling with local port
>     forwarding, and use an Internet browser to open web interfaces hosted
>     on the master node. This method allows you to configure web interface
>     access without using a SOCKS proxy.

to do this use the command

```
$ ssh -gnNT -L 9002:localhost:8088 user@example.com
```

where user@example.com is your username.  Note the use of -g to open access to external ip addresses (beware this is a security risk)

you can check this is running using

```
nmap localhost
```

to close this ssh tunnel when done use

```
ps aux | grep 9002
```

to find the pid of your running ssh process and kill it.

> - Option 2 (recommended for new users): Use an SSH client to connect to the master node, configure SSH tunneling with dynamic port
>     forwarding, and configure your Internet browser to use an add-on such
>     as FoxyProxy or SwitchySharp to manage your SOCKS proxy settings. This
>     method allows you to automatically filter URLs based on text patterns
>     and to limit the proxy settings to domains that match the form of the
>     master node's DNS name. The browser add-on automatically handles
>     turning the proxy on and off when you switch between viewing websites
>     hosted on the master node, and those on the Internet. For more
>     information about how to configure FoxyProxy for Firefox and Google
>     Chrome, see Option 2, Part 2: Configure Proxy Settings to View
>     Websites Hosted on the Master Node.

This seems like insanity to me but I have been unable to find how to configure access in core-site.xml to override the web interface for the ResourceManager which by default it is available at localhost:8088/ and if Amazon think this is the way then I tend to go along with it

Comment: Core site doesn't control ResourceManager address. Yarn site does